# Individual chats for each Stack Overflow article

Tags: discussion, chat

Of course, I'm aware of https://chat.stackoverflow.com/.

However, I think I read somewhere that Stack Overflow also had this feature to display a chat box on each article page. All visitors of the same article would then be in the same chat.

Did Stack Overflow have something like this at any time? And if so, why has it been discontinued?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't automatically have a chat room for each post. But if the comments below a particular question or answer are getting long, the system will prompt anyone about to add another comment and suggest taking the discussion to chat instead of adding a comment.

If a user decides to invite other commenters to chat, the system adds a link to a chat room. For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903777/set-time-schedule-in-codeigniter) that happened, so you see comments like this:

[image]

So, to answer your question, we don't create it automatically, but it is possible to have a per-post chat *when that becomes necessary*.

Comment: That sounds like a very meaningful approach. Thanks for clarifying!